# How to access fleurons?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I'm just wondering, how is it possible to access and use the fleurons coming with fonts like Garamond Premier Pro. For example, the MinionPro package, with pifont, gives a comfortable interface for this purpose:

```
\usepackage{pifont}
\Pisymbol{MinionPro-Extra}{110}
```

What i have to do to display, for example, that beautyful leaf, located at U+E1C0 (Orn.01) in the GaramondPremrPro.otf? Is it related also somehow to the installation of the fonts (i used otftotfm)? Or is there a package providing an interface to access these symbols?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For "normal" TeX fonts its `{\somefontcommand \char<number>}` (which is basically what `Pisymbol` does). But I'm not sure for fonts with more than 256 glyphs.

Comment: @Martin It works the same in XeTeX: ``\char"E1C0`` (the ``"`` is for hexadecimal).

Comment: @egreg: I guessed so. Any chance to use that font with `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Martin: only via reencoding.

Comment: @Martin: Have a look at [autoinst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontools/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**The following will work only with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, with the fontspec package loaded.**

If Garamond Premier is your main font you have to say simply

```
\symbol{\string"E1C0}
```

Otherwise, you need to define a command for accessing that font

```
\newfontface{\fleurons}{Garamond Premier Pro}
```

and use

```
{\fleurons\symbol{\string"E1C0}}
```

There's no interface similar to **pifont**, at the moment.

Note. `\string` is used to avoid bad effects with some languages that may activate the double quote.

**Traditional pdflatex**

For traditional `pdflatex` one might go via reencoding, but this requires also making a TFM file, possibly with **fontinst** or, as Michael Ummels points out, with `otftotfm`, which has also options for extracting ornaments (see also the wrapper script `autoinst`).

The package **adforn** makes available some *fleurons*.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! These commands are for XeLaTeX only? My LaTeX (default tetex in archlinux) says "! Undefined control sequence. \newfontface", and "Bad character code 57792" (yes, btw this is the number of that character in the GaramondPremrPro.otf). Is it possible to use these symbols in LaTeX, or only XeLaTeX can do this trick?

Comment: They are only for XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX), unfortunately.

Comment: Doesn't that require `fontspec`?

Comment: Thanks. So, it seems i'm facing again to learn something new stuff :)

Comment: @Raphink Yes, I'll edit my answer to make it clear.

Comment: IMHO, the easiest way to generate TFM and encoding files for an OpenType font to use with pdftex is via [otftotfm](http://www.lcdf.org/type/otftotfm.1.html) or [autoinst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontools/), which is a wrapper script for otftotfm.