# Beamer bullets with Alegreya Sans

Tags: beamer, fonts

I find Alegreya Sans especially readable for presentations, in part because it has real italics and not just an oblique shape. However, itemization is problematic.

Although the default, triangular bullets of `beamer` work as expected, the circle, ball, and square options produce miniature bullets, and the latter two are lower than they should be.

For example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{AlegreyaSans}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Tiny Bullets}

  \structure{default}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item An item.
  \end{itemize}

  \structure{circle}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item An item.
  \end{itemize}

  \structure{ball}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Another item.
  \end{itemize}

  \structure{square}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Yet another item.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of pdftex]

I get the same results with `luatex`, but `xetex` stumbles only on the circle:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setsansfont{Alegreya Sans}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Tiny Bullets}

  \structure{default}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item An item.
  \end{itemize}

  \structure{circle}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item An item.
  \end{itemize}

  \structure{ball}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[ball]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Another item.
  \end{itemize}

  \structure{square}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Yet another item.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of xetex]

In `luatex`, I can use `luacode` to gain access to the font’s ornaments, among which are circles and squares:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec,luacode}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120762/7883
\begin{luacode}
  documentdata       = documentdata or { }

  local stringformat = string.format
  local texsprint    = tex.sprint
  local slot_of_name = luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name

  documentdata.fontchar = function (chr)
local chr = slot_of_name(font.current(), chr, false)
if chr and type(chr) == "number" then
  texsprint
    (stringformat ([[\char"%X]], chr))
end
  end
\end{luacode}
\def\fontchar#1{\directlua{documentdata.fontchar "#1"}}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\setsansfont{Alegreya Sans}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{cornament}{\fontchar{circle1}}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{sornament}{\fontchar{square1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Custom Bullets}

  \structure{circle}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[cornament]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item An item.
  \end{itemize}

  \structure{square}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[sornament]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Another item.
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of luatex]

Any ideas why this is happening? It makes no difference whether I use the OpenType fonts provided in TeX Live (for reasons unknown, the package author created them by converting google’s Truetype fonts) or the OpenType fonts straight from [the foundry](http://www.huertatipografica.com/fonts/alegreya-sans-ht).

Comment: The problem seems to be in the fact that the Alegreya font has a grossly wrong value of the ex: 1ex at 11pt size (the font used by `beamer`) is 2.04764pt; it's 1.87pt at 10pt size, less than half of what it should be. The square is defined as `\vrule width 1ex height 1ex`, so this explains the problem in this case.

Comment: Please, make a bug report.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg, for your diagnosis of the problem.  I’ve sent both the foundry and Bob Tennent a link to this discussion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{AlegreyaSans}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \fontdimen5\font=\fontcharht\font`\x}
\begin{document}
[ ... ]
```

[image]

For the circle define an own `mycircle` template and use that instead of `circle'

```
\defbeamertemplate{itemize item}{mycircle}{\scalebox{10}{\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\textbullet}}}%% Value 10 only for demo  :-)
\defbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{mycircle}{\huge\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\textbullet}}
\defbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{mycircle}{\huge\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\textbullet}}
```

and then  \structure{circle}

```
 \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[mycircle]
 \begin{itemize}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Herbert. This is a big step forward: now `pdftex` and `luatex` get the ball and the square right, as `xetex` always did, but all three engines still give me a miniature circle. I usually choose the ball anyway, so this is very helpful.

Comment: see my edit for the circles

Comment: Hmmm.  I’m not seeing any change in the circles.  Never knew that circles were so stubborn.

Comment: it is a problem with the font! See my edit for a drastic change :-))