# How to get access to this special character?

Tags: fontspec, unicode, ligatures

I just bought the font Uberschrift which brings tons of ligatures with it, but u nfortunately I'm not able to get access to them.

[image]

I tried to find out wich is the symbol's name and this is what fontmatrix tells me:

[image]

I found it not in the standard latin1 alphabet but in "un-mapped glyphs".

It is symbol I+191.

How do I get access to this ligature with xelatex or luatex with fontspec?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}% babel for Xelatex
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Uberschrift}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Überschrift


\end{document}
```

Comment: Complain with the distributors, who should tell customers how to get the ligatures.

Comment: @egreg: I'm quite sure the answer would be: klick that button on InDesign or similar and they would ask me back: WTF is LaTeX? ;)

Comment: Try `\XeTeXglyph191\relax` or `\XeTeXglyph"191\relax` (the latter uses hexadecimal.

Comment: \XeTeXglyph191\relax works. Great! Thanks. If you would make this an answer, I could accept it as the right one.

Comment: Sorry but they must be a better way to activate the ligatures than getting them through the slot number. Did you try the other options for the `Ligatures` key? Doesn't the description of the font say anything about its open type features? Did you try `otfinfo`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The specimen of that font can be found here: http://www.fonts.info/pub/pdf/uberschrift-typespecimen.pdf With only that I can't figure out, how to to get access to alternative characters. If you could, please let me know how. Should I open a new question for that. What info from otfinfo would be helpful?

Comment: I had already seen that pdf. It doesn't contain the needed informations.  Didn't you get a readme with the font?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: No, there is only this pdf in the folder named Instructions; the License and the otf-file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently, the program you used tells you the glyph index as a decimal number; with XeTeX you can access a glyph by index using `\XeTeXglyph`.

I suggest a macro, instead of the raw primitive:

```
\newcommand{\glyph}[1]{\XeTeXglyph#1\relax}
```

so, after this, you can type

```
Übers\glyph{191}rift
```

Why a macro? Because there could be a similar trick with LuaLaTeX (that I don't know at the moment), and the macro can be adapted to both engines without requiring changing the input.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120762/4427 for a LuaTeX function that should do the job.